# Why doesn't SASS resolve the calculation?

Tags: sass

Why doesn't SASS resolve the calculation?

```
$animation-speed-half-life: 1s;

@for $i from 0 through 31 {
  &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    transition-delay: #{$animation-speed-half-life - $animation-speed-half-life / $i};
  }
}
```

Instead it outputs `transition-delay: 1s - 1s/1;`

Answer (score 1):

Did you already debug it?
I tested your code at Sassmeister (SASS v3.4.21), and it shows me a reference error:

> Base-level rules cannot contain the parent-selector-referencing
>   character '&'.

**DEBUG**

```
$animation-speed-half-life: 1s;
$i: 1;


$test: #{$animation-speed-half-life - $animation-speed-half-life / $i};
@error $test; // this will render '0s' as expected


.parentElement { // comment this to show the reference error
  @for $i from 0 through 31 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      transition-delay: #{$animation-speed-half-life - $animation-speed-half-life / $i};
    }
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Sassmeister Fiddle</kbd>](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/e235dede18ee423b8d90996e402cdd4d)

Not sure, if that's your complete code or just a snippet but it warns me the error I quoted above. It looks for a parent element which doesn't exist. Probably, that's why in your version it won't calculate. The `.parentElement` is just a dummy to provide you the working way.

**POSSIBLE FIX**

Add a `@if`-condition that checks if a parent element exists:

```
@if & { ... }
```

So basically wrap the condition around the loop:

```
@if & {
  @for $i from 0 through 31 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      transition-delay: #{$animation-speed-half-life - $animation-speed-half-life / $i};
    }
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Sassmeister Fiddle</kbd>](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/5c4c42aef411e7544493934b023e5682)

The `if &  { ..` statement is optional. Just wanted to show you how to bug out the error. I am not sure if your SASS version still interpolates the calculation during an error or not.

My own personal way would be using a placeholder without the `if &` statement because a placeholder functions as a parent element and no error will occur. Even if the element doesn't exist but that's what placeholders are for:

```
%test {
  @for $i from 0 through 31 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      transition-delay: #{$animation-speed-half-life - $animation-speed-half-life / $i};
    }
  }
}

parent {
  @extend %test;
}
```

[<kbd>Sassmeister Fiddle</kbd>](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/1193ec4ff6d27685898bb7ec12594519)

A Mixin would work also but your loop doesn't need any parameter to function so a placeholder should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Sass won't calculate that but you don't actually need to interpolate the value of transition-delay, as there's no CSS going on around it.

This would be my implementation of your code:

```
@mixin incremental-transition-delay($child-count, $half-life: 1s) {
  @for $i from 1 through $child-count {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      transition-delay: $half-life - $half-life / $i;
    }
  }
}

.thing {
  @include incremental-transition-delay(32, 1s);
}
```